# Is it possible to prevent web clients from setting Cache-Control when they have permission to upload to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

The client is calling `ref.put(file, metadata)` in order to upload an image. `cacheControl` is part of the `SettableMetadata` defined that can be passed to `put` and `updateMetadata`. Is there a way to forbid clients from setting this? I know that I can asynchronously update it with a cloud function but then the client could just call `updateMetadata` later, and if I have a cloud function that triggers on metadata update to update the metadata, it goes into an infinite loop (tested in emulator).

Comment: Are you granting clients permission to upload objects? If yes, they can set the metadata. Edit your question with details on the authorization of clients.

Comment: The clients have permission to upload objects.

Comment: By what method (public bucket, IAM identity, service account)? Edit your question with details.

Comment: They have permission via the Cloud Storage rules - e.g. a firebase user with UID can upload to images/{UID}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user is able to upload the files directly within Firebase storage, it is assumed they also have permission to define the meta data. You can setup a cloud function that edits the meta data post upload or handle it directly from cloud functions with your upload. it all depends on your flow within your app.

One solution is to have a dedicated directory that users upload to and Cloud functions migrate and process the files to another directory, this would prevent the metadata from being updated by the users.

You could always enforce it from within the client app with the following:

```js
/ Create a reference to the file whose metadata we want to change
var forestRef = storageRef.child('images/forest.jpg');

// Create file metadata to update
var newMetadata = {
  cacheControl: 'public,max-age=300',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

// Update metadata properties
forestRef.updateMetadata(newMetadata)
  .then((metadata) => {
    // Updated metadata for 'images/forest.jpg' is returned in the Promise
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurredd!
  });
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#update_file_metadata